# How to write a cite command that never fails (avoid [??])

Tags: bibliographies, citing

When writing small documents and drafts for my own reference or quick sharing I often leave the bibliography building for a later stage. In this intermediate stage I still want to use the `\cite` (or variants of it) to keep track of bibliography, that will later reference the appropriate entry.

The problem is that when I compile the document I get "[??]" as placeholders. This is distracting and it doesn't even give any information of what is missing. **Is is possible to get a reasonable content in this placeholder that is not "[??]" from the `\cite` command?**

For example if the code is `bla \cite{Einstein1905} bla`, and `Einstein1905` is not in the bibliography yet, I would like to get at least "bla [Einstein1905] bla", until more information is available in the bibliography database (after which it may just appear as "bla [3] bla" o "bla [Eins05] bla" depending on the style.

Also (and ideally) the fallback result "[Einstein1905]" could be typeset in typewriter style or something to still indicate that something is missing.

I know of the package `showkeys` but it doesn't do exactly this, not at least by default.

Comment: Just use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). I think, by default, it does this.