# Can you configure bibtex to ignore some \cite commands?

Tags: bibtex, citing

When I am writing I often will realize I need to put a citation for something I wrote, but I don't have it.  I like to leave myself something to remind myself which reference I need to put in once I add it to my .bib file. Like this:

```
This important thing\cite{Author's 2010 paper about stuff} is important
```

I edit my tex source in vim and I have a vimscript defined to compile my document, but invalid `\cite{}` commands are not handled very gracefully. So my vimscript calls a bash script that makes a copy of my tex source with all such commands commented out.  I find the "invalid" citations using a regular expression that matched my cite-key format. When my colleges ask me to help them set up something similar for themselves it gets really messy when they don't have a well defined cite-key format.

I would like to redefine the way `\cite{}` commands are parsed to ignore ones that begin with a specific character say `*`, although the specific character is not important if one choice is better than the other. So

```
Words in the sentence\cite{author:1990-0} more words.
```

would be handled correctly but say

```
Words in the sentence\cite{*not a real key just a note} more words.
```

would be ignored. Is this possible? How could I find out?

I would also like to have a marker appear in the text to remind me I need to add something there, but that would be like a bonus not a main objective of what I need.

Comment: why not just use \xcite{xxxx} with `\newcommand\xcite[1]{..}`  to do whatever you need? redefining `\cite` is possible but trickier due to all the various packages that give it different definitions

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131641/how-to-write-a-cite-command-that-never-fails-avoid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the optional argument of `\cite` then you have to extend the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\myCite\cite
\makeatletter
\def\cite#1{\cite@I#1!!}
\def\cite@I{\@ifnextchar*\cite@II\cite@III}
\def\cite@II#1!!{}
\def\cite@III#1!!{\myCite{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

foo\cite{article-minimal} and bar\cite{*article-full}

foo\cite{*article-minimal} and bar\cite{article-full}

foo\cite{article-crossref} and bar\cite{*whole-journal}

foo\cite{*article-crossref} and bar\cite{whole-journal}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image]